# Xcode func shows gray instead of white params

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parameters, func

Hello i am working with Xcode and i have noticed that some function are behaving different then usual, for example :

[function showing parameters in gray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIigq.png)

```
  let config = UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil) { [UIMenuElement] in
        let downloadAction = UIAction(title: "Download",subtitle: nil, state: .off) { _ in
            print("download")
        }
```

why does Xcode show the functions in gray and not regular white?

why when i select the function, Xcode writes the function without the parameters and I have to write them out manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the parameters of those overloads are all optional. Optional parameters are all shown in grey* in the autocomplete box in Xcode 14.

If the function has *some* required parameters, and *some* optional parameters, you can see that the required ones are in white, and the optional ones are in grey.

For example:

```
func foo(parameter1: Int = 0, parameter2: Int) {}
```

[image]

To insert all the parameters all at once, you can press option + enter, rather than just enter on its own, after selecting the overload using the arrow keys.

<sup>*</sup> <sub>Upon further inspection, I think it's actually half-transparent, not grey.</sub>

Comment: I wonder is there any settings can change the default behaviors. I prefer xcode13 auto insert parameter ways.

Comment: @frank Maybe in a future version... At least in Xcode 14.0, none of the options in the "Themes" tab correspond to the grey color seen here.